# Disable SalesForce Triggers using SOAP API

Tags: salesforce

I am inserting data to salesforce org using Partner SOAP API but some of the data is not getting inserted because of validations and Triggers on the object

How can i disable validations and triggers before inserting the data?

I want to do it programmatically through the salesforce SOAP API

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can disable them (set to inactive) programmatically.

But, you could have a custom setting operating as a switch, this could be accessed from apex. But this would require you to dd it in all your validation rules and triggers.

so your validtion rules & triggers would go like

> If switch is true  ---> do stuff

and when you want to run code that should not trigger validation rules and triggers

```
> set switch to false
-----> do stuff  
> set switch to true
```

Comment: There's currently a really interesting (if bit overwhelming) question on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/control-fields-vs-heap-mock-fields-for-branching-trigger-behavior It can be a custom setting, a flag on user (if there's 1 designated user account for integration)... But yeah, no way to remotely disable triggers